# How can I make a chrome extension that allows you to text/group chat

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a group chat extension, basically you can open it put in a code to connect to a group chat and then you can talk and stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yours is too broad a question for this site. Please read about the types of questions that are not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask I'm sure you'll find some other place for advice (Quora perhaps?).

Comment: Also please read this (how to ask) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This will be helpful as you edit this question or come back with more questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Udemy and take *several* courses until you feel really comfortable with html, css, js, and Node.js.
2. Learn a few frameworks (Angular, Vue, React, Mithril... have fun and stay safe out there)
3. Pick a framework/stack (eeny meeny miny moe)
4. Start coding (you’ll know what to do if you followed steps 1-3).
5. After coding a bit, you’ll realize this is very hard. Make some friends in the JS community, take more courses, and keep grinding.
6. Take a course on launching Chrome extensions.
7. If you’re still working at it, and feeling optimistic, take a course on security and authorization concerns, and don’t you dare release that app without double checking the security of your Node server.
8. Blow all your money on some cloud services to host your db, server, etc.
9. Profit. (Jk sorta, I’m just tired of typing)